# WPA "Press Alt + Space to show more detail"

Tags: etw, xperf, windows-performance-analyzer

Hovering over a data point in the graph view of Windows Performance Analyzer brings up a small pop-up windows that says "Press Alt + Space to show more detail". But when I do that I get the top level dialog common to all windows which is the dialog that gives you the option to restore, minimize, maximize, and close.

The "WPA Keyboard Shortcuts" page at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn450837.aspx makes no mention of "Alt + Space". Neither do google, bing, or duck duck go searches.

The old xperfview would show all the data associated with a data point when hovering over it. How do I do that in WPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> works fine.

Here is the smaller default value:

[image]

and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> shows more details:

[image]

This is an issue with your keyboard/system.

Comment: Thanks. Now to figure out what's wrong with my keyboard.

Comment: MS doc says, "Alt + Spacebar Open the shortcut menu for the active window".  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts#keyboard-shortcuts=windows-7  This is the behavior I'm seeing.